# Using omp atomic operation in OpenMP for class members with Eigen Array

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen, eigen3

I doing simulations of `N` particles that interact between each other in a given range. To avoid a `N^2` computation over the particle, I sort (spatially) the particles in an array in which I stored the index of one particle and then each particles points to another particle which is in the same box. I have already written a sequential code in C++ and I am trying to implement a OpenMP version to increase the number of particles. To define particles and the array I use two classes

```
class Boxes
{
    int m_NX;
    int m_NY;
    int m_Nboxes;
    Eigen::ArrayXi m_boxes;
...
};

class Particles
{
        int m_nbParticles;
        Eigen::ArrayXd m_positions;
        Eigen::ArrayXi m_nextParticles;
...
};
```

Then to sort the particles I doing this

```
void updateBoxes(Boxes &p_boxes, Particles &p_particles)
{
...
    for (int i = 0; i < p_particles.m_nbParticles; i++)
    {
        indexX = p_particles.position(i).x() / dX;
        indexY = p_particles.position(i).y() / dX;
        indexBox = indexX + NXboxes*indexY;
        p_particles.m_nextParticles[i] = p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox];
        p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox] = i;
    }
}
```

I try to parallelize this part by adding `pragma omp atomic` but I get an error at the compile

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < p_particles.size(); i++)
    {
        indexX = p_particles.position(i).x() / dX;
        indexY = p_particles.position(i).y() / dX;
        indexBox = indexX + NXboxes*indexY;
        #pragma omp atomic
        p_particles.m_nextParticles[i] = p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox];
        #pragma omp atomic
        p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox] = i;

    }
```

But it doesn work and I get an error at compile time.

```
error: the statement for 'atomic' must be an expression statement of form '++x;', '--x;', 'x++;', 'x--;', 'x binop= expr;', 'x = x binop expr' or 'x = expr binop x', where x is an l-value expression with scalar type
```

I already parallelized the other part of the code and even if this part is around 8% of the total time for a single thread code, it becomes more and more important when I increase the number of thread. I am relatively new with OpenMP and I am stuck on this. What is the best way to parallelize this part of the code?

Comment: For the first one try  `#pragma omp atomic read`, and for the second one try `#pragma omp atomic write`.

Comment: That said, are you sure that there is no dependency between the iterations? If there is, then you simply cannot parallelize the loop, even with atomic directives.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Now with `#pragma omp atomic read/write` the compilation works, but increasing the number of threads increase the total time of the routine.
In theory, there is only few dependencies, because particles are reorganised in memory (close particle in space are close in memory). Should I add a `static` keyword to `#pragma omp for` instruction?

Comment: "few dependencies" is still "dependencies": the code will run, but you will get unpredictable results. If the same `indexBox` value is obtained in different iterations, then you can't predict which value will be set in `p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox]`. Beside, I completely missed that `indexX` , `indexY`, and `indexBox` should be declared as `private` (or should be declared within the loop).

Comment: I understand. Is it possible to use lock instruction in that case to avoid problems if two threads try to access and modify the same `p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox]` ... which should happen very rarely. Otherwise I will keep the code like this. Thank you very much for your remark.

Comment: Is the entire point of this operation to create a sort of single-linked list from one particle in a box to the next particle in the same box?

Comment: Yes exactly. This point allow to track close particles easily.

Comment: Note that a linked-list like structure will slow you down when iterating over it due to [pointer chasing](https://en.algorithmica.org/hpc/cpu-cache/latency/) (well, index chasing in this case, but same principle). If you use a vector of indices per block, you can iterate faster while having basically the same overhead (one index per particle). Doesn't solve your parallelization issue but would make everything else faster

Comment: Also, there are algorithms and data structures that are specifically built for grouping and searching in spatial data, for example finding nearest neighbours. Have you checked whether those are helpful in your program, e.g. [Boost's Spatial Indexes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/introduction.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mentioned in my comments, I think it is the wrong approach to start with this sort of linked list-like structure since [pointer chasing](https://en.algorithmica.org/hpc/cpu-cache/latency/) will negatively impact performance, especially for large particle lists. But to show this, we have to make a benchmark and a minimum reproducible example. So I modify the shown code for this.

### Original approach

```cpp
struct Boxes
{
    int m_NX;
    int m_NY;
    double m_boxsize;
    Eigen::ArrayXi m_boxes;

    Boxes(int NX, int NY, double boxsize)
    : m_NX(NX),
      m_NY(NY),
      m_boxsize(boxsize),
      m_boxes(Eigen::ArrayXi::Constant(NX * NY, -1))
    {}
};
```

Since the original question didn't make this abundantly clear: `m_boxes` contains the index of one particle in the respective box. I chose to denote the end of the linked list (no particles in the box) as particle index -1.

```cpp
struct Particles
{
    Eigen::Array2Xd m_positions;
    Eigen::ArrayXi m_nextParticles;

    explicit Particles(int N)
    : m_positions(Eigen::Array2Xd::Random(2, N).abs()),
      m_nextParticles(Eigen::ArrayXi::Constant(N, -1))
    {}
    int nbParticles() const noexcept
    { return static_cast<int>(m_positions.cols()); }
};
```

Again to explain the original design, `m_nextParticles` holds, for each particle, the index of the next one in the same box. And again -1 indicates the end of the list.

Two further changes / optimizations:

1. The member `m_nbParticles` was redundant as both arrays know their size and therefore the number of particles
2. I changed the array type to `Array2Xd` since we deal with 2D coordinates. One column per particle (`Array2Xd` instead of `ArrayX2d`) is more efficient, at least for the processing we do in my example, because Eigen is column-major
3. For testing, I build random particles in the range [0, 1)

```cpp
void link_list(Boxes& p_boxes, Particles& p_particles)
{
    p_boxes.m_boxes.fill(-1);
    p_particles.m_nextParticles.fill(-1);
    const double boxscale = 1. / p_boxes.m_boxsize;
    for(int i = 0, n = p_particles.m_positions.cols(); i < n; ++i) {
        Eigen::Array2i coords =
            (p_particles.m_positions.col(i) * boxscale).cast<int>();
        int indexBox = coords.y() * p_boxes.m_NX + coords.x();
        p_particles.m_nextParticles[i] =
            std::exchange(p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox], i);
    }
}
```

A slightly optimized version of the original that avoids the two divisions of the original. It is not parallelized and I don't think it can realistically be done. Maybe by replacing the `std::exchange` with an atomic exchange. But given the cost of that operation and the constant cache line bouncing it will produce, I doubt this is viable.

For benchmarking, we need some code to actually make use of the list. I chose a simple, parallelized iteration over each box that computes the center of mass per bin. Nothing fancy, nothing realistic, but the access pattern may be close to a real use case:

```cpp
Eigen::Array2Xd traverse_list(const Boxes& p_boxes, Particles& p_particles)
{
    const int n = p_boxes.m_boxes.size();
    Eigen::Array2Xd center(2, n);
#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Eigen::Array2d sum = Eigen::Array2d::Zero();
        int pcount = 0;
        int particleIndex = p_boxes.m_boxes[i];
        while(particleIndex >= 0) {
            sum += p_particles.m_positions.col(particleIndex);
            pcount += 1;
            particleIndex = p_particles.m_nextParticles[particleIndex];
        }
        center.col(i) = sum / static_cast<double>(pcount);
    }
    return center;
}
```

My benchmark run looks like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int n_particles = 10000000, n_boxes = 200, n_repetitions = 10, n_traversals = 10;
    Boxes boxes(n_boxes, n_boxes, 1. / n_boxes);
    Particles particles(n_particles);
    for(int i = 0; i < n_repetitions; ++i) {
        link_list(boxes, particles);
        for(int j = 0; j < n_traversals; ++j)
            traverse_list(boxes, particles);
    }
}
```

Runtime on my 8 core 16 thread system is

```
real    0m7,727s
user    1m56,050s
sys     0m0,385s
```

I expect performance to be worse on systems without hyperthreading where pointer chasing will stall the entire core.

### Alternative approach

Instead of constructing a linked list, we can use a vector of particles per box. That avoids the pointer chasing, makes traversal easier, and allows some more independent operations. The memory requirement stays practically the same. Only the fixed overhead per box grows.

```cpp
struct Boxes
{
    int m_NX;
    int m_NY;
    double m_boxsize;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_boxes;

    Boxes(int NX, int NY, double boxsize)
    : m_NX(NX),
      m_NY(NY),
      m_boxsize(boxsize),
      m_boxes(static_cast<unsigned>(NX * NY))
    {}
    static Boxes empty_like(const Boxes& p_o)
    { return Boxes(p_o.m_NX, p_o.m_NY, p_o.m_boxsize); }
};
struct Particles
{
    Eigen::Array2Xd m_positions;

    explicit Particles(int N)
    : m_positions(Eigen::Array2Xd::Random(2, N).abs())
    {}
};
```

To fill the boxes, we start with a sequential algorithm for comparison:

```cpp
void link_list(Boxes& p_boxes, Particles& p_particles)
{
    for(std::vector<int>& box: p_boxes.m_boxes)
        box.clear();
    const double boxscale = 1. / p_boxes.m_boxsize;
    for(int i = 0, n = p_particles.m_positions.cols(); i < n; ++i) {
        Eigen::Array2i coords =
            (p_particles.m_positions.col(i) * boxscale).cast<int>();
        unsigned indexBox = static_cast<unsigned>(
            coords.y() * p_boxes.m_NX + coords.x());
        p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox].push_back(i);
    }
}
```

And the traversal function:

```cpp
Eigen::Array2Xd traverse_list(const Boxes& p_boxes, Particles& p_particles)
{
    const std::size_t n = p_boxes.m_boxes.size();
    Eigen::Array2Xd center(2, static_cast<Eigen::Index>(n));
#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Eigen::Array2d sum = Eigen::Array2d::Zero();
        for(int particleIndex: p_boxes.m_boxes[i])
            sum += p_particles.m_positions.col(particleIndex);
        center.col(static_cast<Eigen::Index>(i)) =
            sum / static_cast<double>(p_boxes.m_boxes[i].size());
    }
    return center;
}
```

We still have a chaotic memory access pattern when reading the coordinates but we got rid of the loop-carried dependency on the next particle index. Instead, this code only has a loop-carried dependency chain on the sum, which of course is part of the example, not the real application. This runs at

```
real    0m5,032s
user    1m6,940s
sys     0m0,394s
```

We can try parallelizing the `link_list` function, too. However, the best I could come up with requires some temporary memory and cross-thread communication.

```cpp
void link_list(Boxes& p_boxes, Particles& p_particles)
{
    const double boxscale = 1. / p_boxes.m_boxsize;
    const std::size_t n_boxes = p_boxes.m_boxes.size();
    const int n_particles = static_cast<int>(p_particles.m_positions.cols());
    using box_ptr = Boxes*;
    const std::unique_ptr<box_ptr[]> threadboxes =
        std::make_unique<box_ptr[]>(omp_get_max_threads());
#   pragma omp parallel
    {
        const int threadcount = omp_get_num_threads();
        const int threadid = omp_get_thread_num();
        Boxes own_boxes = Boxes::empty_like(p_boxes);
        threadboxes[threadid] = &own_boxes;
#       pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0; i < n_particles; ++i) {
            Eigen::Array2i coords =
                (p_particles.m_positions.col(i) * boxscale).cast<int>();
            unsigned indexBox = static_cast<unsigned>(
                coords.y() * own_boxes.m_NX + coords.x());
            own_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox].push_back(i);
        }
#       pragma omp for
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < n_boxes; ++i) {
            // move to local to reduce cache-line bouncing
            std::vector<int> box = std::move(p_boxes.m_boxes[i]);
            box.clear();
            for(int j = 0; j < threadcount; ++j) {
                const std::vector<int>& threadbox =
                    threadboxes[j]->m_boxes[i];
                box.insert(box.end(), threadbox.begin(), threadbox.end());
            }
            p_boxes.m_boxes[i] = std::move(box);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is pretty simple. We use two phases:

1. We create a `Boxes` structure per thread that each thread can fill individually with a subset of all particles
2. We concatenate all partial boxes into the final result

This is very similar to how one would parallelize a histogram computation. In fact, we run into many of the same issues and can probably apply the same techniques.

There are four problems with this approach:

1. The temporary memory allocations cost performance
2. When concatenating, we cause a lot of cross-CPU communication
3. We invoke several implicit thread barriers (one per loop)
4. The actual work we do to compute the box of each particle is very small. We start with an algorithm that is mostly memory-constrained and then add more memory operations on top

All in all, this is not faster, at least on my system.

```
real    0m5,852s
user    1m26,415s
sys     0m0,757s
```

### Final thoughts

1. I already mentioned that this kind of fixed pattern bin may not be ideal. Other structures like R-trees are specifically built for checking nearest neighbours and similar tasks.

Boost's [Spatial Indexes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/introduction.html) have a handy, if not well documented, implementation. A fixed grid can still work fine but mostly for densely packed and equally distributed data where you also know the search radii a-priori

If your particle dataset is mostly read-only, sorting into a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=K-d_tree&oldid=1115861309) can be done with zero memory overhead and just [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

2. Once you start modifying the particles while iterating over the boxes, performance will suffer through cache-line bouncing and possibly running out of store-buffers. A chaotic write pattern by multiple threads on the same data structure is simply not ideal. If this is something you do, consider actually sorting the particles spatially so that particles in the same box are also located together. This applies to both approaches of traversing the blocks

Comment: Indeed, if there isn't particle inside a box the index is set to -1.
The particles are more or less homogeneously distributed, the density is high, the size of the boxes is corresponding to the size of the radii of interaction. To compute the interaction acting on one particle I only need to check the boxes around.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox] = i;
```

can have multiple writes into the same location. Often in this sort of conversions from serial to parallel there will be a reduction happening (say, a sum) and you need to worry about how to parallelize that.

In your serial code however, only the last one of these is preserved. If you don't care about preserving precisely the serially last one, and *any* saved `i` value is good, then you indeed declare this statement atomic and you'll be fine.

Comment: From the comments I figured that they build basically a single linked list. The ```m_boxes``` are the list heads. The ```m_nextParticles``` are the next pointers (well, indices, but same principle). The loop basically adds the i-th pointer to the front of the list for its box. At this point, maybe an atomic exchange could solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem mentioned in the comments and the previous answer I try

```
    omp_lock_t lock[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        omp_init_lock(&(lock[i]));
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
    {
        int indexX, indexY, indexBox;
        indexX = p_particles.position(i).x() / dX;
        indexY = p_particles.position(i).y() / dX;
        indexBox = indexX + NXboxes*indexY;
        omp_set_lock(&(lock[i]));
        p_particles.m_nextParticles[i] = p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox];
        p_boxes.m_boxes[indexBox] = i;
        omp_unset_lock(&(lock[i]));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        omp_destroy_lock(&(lock[i]));
```

But the routine becomes incredibly slow (x30). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Locks are very slow, especially when used this way. The serial version could loop at something like 1 iteration per 4-8 clock cycles, mostly limited by the division. Mutex locking and unlocking, even in the best case, takes something like 40 clock cycles. That's not taking into account cache line bouncing and lock contention

Comment: In fact, performance is not the biggest issue here: there is still a *race condition* since `lock[i]` is locked instead of `lock[indexBox]`. `i` is guaranteed to be different in each thread so it does not make sense to set the `i`th lock.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Indeed I did a mistake. It was wrong. But after changing the index the performance issue is the same.

Comment: @Homer512 Now I understand. I am using a lecture in which they only explain the different ways to protect data without much more detail. Do you recommend a book ?

Comment: @Hunken how about [Preshing's blog](https://preshing.com/20111118/locks-arent-slow-lock-contention-is/) If you want to know the cost of specific operations, check [Agner](https://www.agner.org/optimize/)